# StaticInjectorError(AppModule) Error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I only just started learning how to work with Angular 2 and Ionic 3.20.0 but now facing a challenge. I'm trying to display product images in my home page but the app is throwing this error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> ProductProvider]

I have imported the ProductProvider service and added it to providers in my app.module.ts file.

```
import { ProductProvider } from '../providers/product/product';

@NgModule({
...  
providers: [
  StatusBar,
  SplashScreen,
  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  ProductProvider
]
```

Now this is the products.ts and home.ts files respectively

product.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ProductProvider {

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  console.log('Hello ProductProvider Provider');
}

getProducts(){
   return this.http.get('/assets/data.json')
     .map(response => response);
}
}
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { ProductProvider } from '../../providers/product/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
public allProducts = [];

constructor(private productProvide: ProductProvider, private http: Http, 
public navCtrl: NavController) {

}

ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.productProvide.getProducts()
      .subscribe((response) => {
    this.allProducts = response;
});
}
}
```

Why is my code throwing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not specify the type returned in getProducts() method of ProductProvider so http client assumed it was an object being returned and that caused the error. I was able to fix it by adding any[] to http get like this `return this.http.get<any[]>('/assets/data.json')`

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the provider with the command:

```
ionic g provider <provider_name>
```

Ionic CLI will generate all the necessary things

Comment: ProductProvider is already existing and has been imported in home.ts file as posted in the question. I get the mentioned error when trying to use the data in home but console.log does not throw an error

Comment: Yeah, I simulate the error. Actually you have to import HttpClient and HttpHandler providers and add in app.module. You can import from '@angular/common/http' and add it in the providers. It worked for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: Appreciate the effort. Posted my solution down there